# asp.net maintaining viewstate with get

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

Upon page reloads I want to retain the values the user had typed in upon hitting submit.

I worry about viewstates being cumbersome for pages, both in bandwidth and in time for a page viewer to download the page.  I am cheap with my bytes :p

My question is instead of using server controls and such I am having the form on the page do a get to itself and on the aspx putting

```
<input type="text" id="user_email" name="email" value="<%=Request.Form["email"] %>" />
```

This allows me to not use viewstate.  Are there any potential shortcomings to doing things this way?  My goal is always for a lighter page and efficiency even if it is more work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: remember: not only the value is stored inside the viewstate!

Comment: I agree with Adreas. Remember that ControlState is also stored in the hidden VIEWSTATE field. When working with ASP.NET web forms, I always derive my pages from a custom base class which essentially eliminates all view / control state from the page (and disables "post backs"). Obviously, the JS scripts are still being referenced and the hidden fields are rendered to the page, but it's already a hell of a lot better than stock web forms.

Comment: another input: is processing the viewstate and transferal of the hiddenfields really your bottleneck? ... otherwise i wouldn't cope with it!

Comment: another input: to get an idea of what is stored inside the viewstate, copy the content of your `__VIEWSTATE` field to this base64 decoder (http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) and hit `decode safely as text`

Answer (score 1):

This could be a lot of work and it might bite you later if you want to do this work around. 
I would recommend you disable the viewstate on the page or control basis otherwise I think there is no point of using ASP.NET webform, you might want to try looking at ASP.NET MVC Instead.

Comment: +, nothing's easier than `EnableViewState="false"`!

Comment: Not necessarily. Disabling the view state doesn't disable the CONTROL STATE, which also gets plopped into the hidden field. This blog post briefly explains how to completely disable view- AND control state: http://bit.ly/ehGxGn

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using 0 bytes of ViewState data sent to the clients with very little work and with no changes to your existing code: Storing the ViewState on server's file system.

Read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx .

You don't have to read it all, scroll down until you reach the chapter **Specifying Where to Persist the View State**. All you need to do us inherit the Page class used in your pages, override certain ViewState- related methods for changing ViewState behaviour. Example code is in the link.

**Hints**

- You should definitly use SSD storage for this kind of ViewState. On an Azure server the D: Temp- drive is optimized for this type of use.
- For further performance, you could implement a cache- mechanism that primarely uses System.Web.Caching instead of SSD. But only write to SSD when memory is full and cache is about to be wiped. Read more about caching here under *Caching API, Using the Cache object*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx
- If you choose to use Caching, you should also remove the old ViewState from the Cache whenever the same user posts the next time. That would significantly remove memory consumption and probably eliminate need for SSD- write overall most of the time.
- Set a reasonable amount of time to persist the ViewState. On most kinds of pages, 30 min - 1 hour should do be enough.

Please ask me if you want further examples. :)